# Ansible group_vars not loading based on environment / host list

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook like so:

```
- hosts: "{{env}}"
  name: "REDIS Playbook"
  sudo: no
  vars:
    product: redis
  roles:
    - redis
```

And I call it with:  `ansible-playbook pb_redis.yml -i inventory/redis -e env=qa -v`

I have a directory structure like:

```
.
├── group_vars
│   ├── qa
│   │   ├── common
│   │   |    └── redis.yml
│   │   ├── products
│   │   |    └── abc-1.yml
│   │   |    └── xyz-2.yml
│   ├── test
│   │   ├── common
│   │   |    └── redis.yml
│   │   ├── products
│   │   |    └── abc-1.yml
│   │   |    └── xyz-2.yml
├── inventory
└── roles
    └── redis
        ├── files
        ├── handlers
        ├── meta
        ├── tasks
        ├── templates
        └── vars
```

And I have an inventory like:

```
[qa:children]
qa_redis

[qa_redis]
mybox.1.space
mybox.2.space
mybox.3.space
```

**My Issue**: When I run `ansible-playbook pb_redis.yml -i inventory/redis -e env=qa -v`, I'm still picking up `group_vars` defined in the `../test/common/redis.yml` instead of `../qa/common/redis.yml` -- am I misunderstanding how this should work? The correct *hosts* get picked up from the inventory file, but not the correct *group_vars*. Should I place the `redis.yml` under `../qa/products/` instead?

Comment: Do you have same hosts defined in `test` and `qa` groups in your inventory?

Comment: Hmm.. yes actually we do. We share hosts for `qa`, `dev`, `test`, `cert` -- defined in that order.

Answer (score 2):

Inventory (host and group) variables in Ansible are bound to host. Group variables exist for convenience.

If a host is in multiple groups at the same time, all group variables are applied to that host.
If different groups have same variables, they overwrite each other during inventory load process.

So if you have `mybox.1.space` in groups `qa` and `test`, variables from groups `qa` and `test` are applied to this host.

Usually you want to use separate inventories to work with different deploy environments. And groups are used to separate different logical units inside inventory.