# Ansible with multiple bastion hosts and ssh keys reverts to ~/.ssh/id_rsa rather than assigned pem file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to use ansible (2.2.1.0) in order to run a healthcheck playbook I wrote with a couple of hosts situated behind two bastion hosts.

I have two environments, dev and prod, and two SSH keys for each environment (which are different). Each environment has a bastion host that you need to SSH into first in order to reach any other hosts in that environment. The problem is that it seems that ansible is using the correct SSH keys for the bastion hosts, but it seems to revert to ~/.ssh/id_rsa for any of the hosts behind the bastion boxes.

My `hosts` inventory:

```
[jumpbox-dev]
DEV-BASTION ansible_ssh_host=XX.XX.XX.XX

[dev]
WEB1 ansible_ssh_host=10.0.0.1
WEB2 ansible_ssh_host=10.0.0.2

[jumpbox-prod]
PROD-BASTION ansible_ssh_host=YY.YY.YY.YY

[prod]
WEB3 ansible_ssh_host=10.0.0.1
WEB4 ansible_ssh_host=10.0.0.2
```

under `group_vars` I have the files:

```
group_vars
- jumpbox-dev.yml
- dev.yml
- jumpbox-prod.yml
- prod.yml
```

My healthcheck.yml is

```
---
- name: Ping all hosts
  become: True
  hosts:
    - jumpbox-dev
    - dev
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Ping
    ping:
```

`jumpbox-dev.yml` contains `ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /home/myUser/.ssh/id_rsa_dev`, and `dev.yml` contains: `ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q myUser@XX.XX.XX.XX"'`

Specifying the `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` in dev.yml seems to be ignored, but all the requests succeed if I copy `id_rsa_dev` into `id_rsa` in my `/home/myUser/.ssh` folder. Adding `-i /home/myUser/.ssh/id_rsa_dev` to the proxycommand doesn't seem to help either.

Is there some config I am missing? Could it be related to my directory structure (going through github issues suggests that they might be related)?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Never do environment isolation using groups in Ansible – use different inventories! See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43787923/2795592). In your case variables from `dev.yml` are overwritten by vars from `prod.yml` because WEB1 and WEB2 are in both groups.

Comment: Hey, thanks or replying. I will update my original answer with different names, as they are actually different. I will look into using different inventories and update this, thanks!